# Laravel as a proxy and cookie handling with guzzle

Tags: php, laravel, cookies, laravel-5, guzzle

Here's the deal, one AngularJS app makes a post login request to my API (Laravel). Then Laravel does a request with Guzzle to another API. This API returns a cookie, which Laravel will send over to AngularJS.

Now on subsequent requests made by AngularJS, this cookie is sent, Laravel injects it on subsequent Guzzle requests.

My login method:

```
public function login(AuthRequest $request)
    {
        $credentials = $request->only('email', 'password');
        $response = $this->httpClient->post('_session', [
            'form_params' => [
                'name'     => $credentials['email'],
                'password' => $credentials['password']
            ]
        ]);

        return $this->respond($response->getHeader('Set-Cookie'));
    }
```

How do I "sync" the Laravel cookie and the Guzzle cookie?

I'm using Laravel 5 and the latest Guzzle (6.0.1).

Comment: One simple thought (and I may be misunderstanding the problem) - save the Guzzle cookie in the Laravel session & retrieve it as needed.

Comment: That's what I tried, but reading the docs about cookies on Guzzle I didn't find a way to set a cookie per request. This is the only info about cookies that is on Guzzle docs http://docs.guzzlephp.org/en/latest/quickstart.html#cookies

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to get the created cookie from the Guzzle request using the [Cookie Jar](http://docs.guzzlephp.org/en/latest/request-options.html#cookies)

```
public function login($credentials){
    $jar = new \GuzzleHttp\Cookie\CookieJar;
    $response = CouchDB::execute('post','_session', [
        'form_params' => [
            'name'     => 'email_'.$credentials['email'],
            'password' => $credentials['password']
        ],
        'cookies' => $jar
    ]);

    $user = CouchDB::parseStream($response);
    //Here I'm using the $jar to get access to the cookie created by the Guzzle request
    $customClaims = ['name' => $credentials['email'], 'token' => $jar->toArray()[0]['Value']];
    CouchDB::setToken($customClaims['token']);

    $payload = \JWTFactory::make($customClaims);

    $token = \JWTAuth::encode($payload);
    $user->token = $token->get();

    return $user;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try manually adding CookieJar as specified in [documentation](http://docs.guzzlephp.org/en/latest/request-options.html#cookies). So your client's cookies will be used in request.

```
$jar = new \GuzzleHttp\Cookie\CookieJar();
$client->request('GET', '/get', ['cookies' => $jar]);
```

Comment: True, that's what I eventually did, totally forgot to answer my own question